# Почему при изменении одного экземпляра класса меняется другой?

Tags: java

Имеется класс `Parametr`, которые включает в себя 3 свойства - `str1`, `str2`, `str3` - и один метод `setStr1`:

```
class Parametr {
    String str1, str2, str3;

    Parametr(String str1, String str2, String str3) {
        this.str1 = str1;
        this.str2 = str2;
        this.str3 = str3;
    }

    public void setStr1(String str1) {
        this.str1 = str1;
    }
}
```

Объявляем один экземпляр класса:

```
Parametr par = new Parametr("1", "2", "3");
```

Теперь я хочу объявить еще один экземпляр, который, по сути, является копией этого экземпляра, но отличается другим значением `str1`. Для этого создаем новый экземпляр и присваиваем ему существующий:

```
Parametr par2 = par;
```

И с помощью метода `setStr1` меняем ему значение:

```
par2.setStr1("888");
```

Однако у меня получатся так, что свойство `str1` меняется и у первого экземпляра класса, хотя этот метод должен был подействовать только на второй. Это упрощенный пример, но суть одинакова. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Брр.. Ну блоки с кода я выделил, но что оно так небрежно написано? Даже регистр не соблюдается, как будто прям в форме для вопроса печаталось с телефона...

Comment: Угадали :) спасибо

Comment: Так, @Regent отступы поправил. Интересно, кто придёт третьим, чтобы регистр у ключевых слов и классов поправить? И четвёртым для создания объекта `par`?

Comment: Сам автор поменял всё и покаялся о содеянном

Comment: @Regent, имеем ли мы право менять опечатки, делающий код некомпилирующимся, но при этом не относящиеся к сути вопроса? На мой взгляд - да. Вот если бы вопрос был, почему этот код не компилируется, то однозначно нет.

Comment: Все верно в ответе. В данном случае у вас на один и тот же объект ссылаются две переменных

Comment: @Regent, доправил остатки. А сделать - элементарно - писать код с телефона с авторасстановкой заглавных букв, что я и предположил в первом комментарии.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Для этого создаем новый экземпляр и потсваиваем ему существующий.
>
> ```
> Parametr par2 = par;
> ```

Это не создание нового, а копирование ссылки. Новый создаётся через `new`.

Comment: То есть необходимо сначала объявить новый класс. Присвоить значение, а потом менять переменную через метод set?

Comment: Необходимо создать новый объект. `Parametr par = new Parametr("888", "2", "3");`

Comment: @АрсенШогенов не _"объявить новый класс"_, а _"создать новый объект этого же класса"_.

Answer (score 2):

Объект – это не переменная. Это ссылка на область памяти.
В данном случае, вы просто скопировали ссылку =)

Comment: Клонирование–то тут причем?